# Test focus on a HTML element in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a page where there are list of items listed (5 initially) and then have a load more button when activated will load 5 more items in the list. From an Accessibility point of view, I am working on setting the focus on the newly loaded content when the Load More button is activated. I was able to come up with a logic to get the focus working. I just want to write unit test to make sure that the focus method is called and the focus is set on the correct element.

Here is my function that sets focus:

```js
setFocusOnList(listLength: number) {
   // Set dynamic focus on the newly loaded card when activating Load more button
    if(listLength %5 === 0) {
      this.index = listLength - 5;
    }
    else {
      this.index = listLength - listLength %5;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      const wrapperDiv = document.querySelector('#entity-wrapper-' + this.index) as HTMLElement;
      if (wrapperDiv) {
        wrapperDiv.focus();
      }
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately, that is all the code that I can share. I am not able to wrap my head on how to test the focus method using Jasmine. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the focus event on the element using dispatchEvent.

```js
/*
Your implementation goes here
*/
let loadMore = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#loadmore'); // user your element id
loadMore.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
fixture.detectChanges(); // to detect the changes
/*
Your expectations goes here
*/
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: My HTML element that I am trying to select is as follows:
    <div class="entity-wrapper" *ngFor="let items of list; let i = index" id="entity-wrapper-{{ i }}" tabindex="-1">

Whenever I try to select this element and call the focus method, I am getting NULL since the element selected is null.

Comment: please ensure that you have values in your list.